# Git for Windows: how to apply changes in PATH without reboot?

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I'm using Git for Windows on Windows 7.

When I adjust the `PATH` environment variable, the changes are not applied immediately for console windows.

In order to force applying the changes for a conventional console window, it's necessary to close and reopen the console.

But this doesn't work for Git Bash console window. Changes to `PATH` are applied in Git Bash only after reboot.

Questions:

1. Why
2. How do I force applying the changes in PATH for Git Bash without rebooting? Is there some command that can do this?

Comment: Restarting Git Bash works for me. `$ git --version` => `git version 1.8.0.msysgit.0`

Comment: Confirmed, restarting git bash works for me too

Comment: Any way to do this without restarting the git bash session? I have this problem but can't restart the git bash session, because it's running in a CI environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay, my problem was that i was starting Git Bash from a file manager's context menu. Without being restarted, the file manager remembered the obsolete PATH and somehow transferred it to Git Bash.

Thanks to @gronostaj and @Forza for testing this issue.